# Swift collectionview cell animation only runs when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to animate a collectionview between list and grid layout.

It animates fine between the two layouts but I dont know how to animate some constraints.

Eg:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PhoneCollectionViewCell

        if collectionView.collectionViewLayout == listLayout {
            cell.leadingConst.constant = -20
        } else {
            cell.leadingConst.constant = 10
        }

        return cell
    }
```

This will only change the constraint when I start to scroll and new items appear on the screen. I would like to change the constraint when I change layout.

Method to change layout:

```
@IBAction func gridButtonDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {        
        if collectionView.collectionViewLayout == gridLayout {
            // list layout
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.listLayout, animated: false)
            })
        } else {
            // grid layout
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.gridLayout, animated: false)
            })
        }

    }


override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

class GridLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var numberOfColumns: Int = 3

    init(numberOfColumns: Int) {
        super.init()
        minimumLineSpacing = 1
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 1

        self.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var itemSize: CGSize {
        get {
            if let collectionView = collectionView {
                let itemWidth: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.width/CGFloat(self.numberOfColumns)) - self.minimumInteritemSpacing
                let itemHeight: CGFloat = 260.0
                return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
            }

            // Default fallback
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
        set {
            super.itemSize = newValue
        }
    }

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return proposedContentOffset
    }

}


class ListLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var itemHeight: CGFloat = 180

    init(itemHeight: CGFloat) {
        super.init()
        minimumLineSpacing = 1
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 1

        self.itemHeight = itemHeight
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var itemSize: CGSize {
        get {
            if let collectionView = collectionView {
                let itemWidth: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width
                return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: self.itemHeight)
            }

            // Default fallback
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
        set {
            super.itemSize = newValue
        }
    }

    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return proposedContentOffset
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing 'animated' to true in 'self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.listLayout, animated: false)'?

Comment: @almas Yeah I have tried that, same thing happens